# Tensorflow how to transfer tensors machine to machine

Tags: tensorflow

I'm studying tensorflow r1.3, I want to know send/receive process machine to machine and device to device.

As I know, Rendezvous class is related to send/receive tensors device to device. Then is there other classes which are related to send/receive tensors machine to machine? I think Rendezvous work along device (such as ..task:0/gpu:0..) so it could have role of send/receive process from machine to machine but I'm not sure.

I want to check it specifically in tensorflow source code however it was hard to figure out. If I can know the concrete source(file), please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Distributed TensorFlow implementation is found in the [`tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime) directory of the TensorFlow repository. It contains the [`RpcRemoteRendezvous`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/dc65f63c3d5c22eea00833abe72f9b5cd8a662ba/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/rpc_rendezvous_mgr.cc) class, which is an implementation of the `Rendezvous` interface that uses RPC to retrieve tensor values from a different machine.

The [TensorFlow Architecture](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture) guide has more details on how TensorFlow graphs are split across machines, and tensors flow between them.

Comment: Thanks for reply mrry. I'm glad to get some comments from you. Actually I already ongoing seeing that class. However I saw the other class which is GdrRemoteRendezvous class. Is this class also related to sending tensors from machine to machine? Actually I want to know what the class GdrRemoteRendezvous class. What is Gdr mean?